# Problem with dpkg-preconfigure, how to correct?

Tags: 12.04, apt, dpkg, teamviewer

I was trying to install TeamViewer, and I followed the instructions [here](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/12/quickly-install-teamviewer-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/) even though they specify 11.10 instead of 12.04 (what I'm running).

In particular, I executed.

```
$ wget http://www.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb
```

The `dpkg` command failed, and after this point my packaging system has been broken. The software center instructs me to try:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

which leads to

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  teamviewer7:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 89.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 81.9 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main dash amd64 0.5.7-2ubuntu2 [89.0 kB]
Fetched 89.0 kB in 1s (83.9 kB/s)
E: Sub-process /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true returned an error code (100)
E: Failure running script /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true
```

At this point I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2):

First, remove Teamviewer with:

```
sudo dpkg -r teamviewer7
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I'll upvote, but not accept, because I have no way of confirming. Things got worse from here, to where I had no working terminal, and then couldn't boot. I reinstalled.

Comment: This command won't work because `bash`, `dash` and `sh` have been deleted. So, root won't be able to access it; the evidence is here:

    `E: Sub-process /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true returned an error code (100)
    E: Failure running script /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true`

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue and fixed it just now. I made three mistakes:

First, I downloaded it, attempted to install it and I realized my archive manager wasn't working properly. Next, when I tried to remove the package, the root user couldn't access `dpkg`, so I deferred the uninstall. Third was the worst: I restarted. By restarting Ubuntu 12.04, the OS was stuck booting forever just as you describe.

Fortunately, I had a copy of Finnix 103: http://www.finnix.org/. After a bit of analysis on the hard drive partition, I realized that `bash`, `dash` and `sh` have been deleted from the `/bin` directory. So, I copied them over from the Finnix installation:

```
# mount <ubuntu_partition> /mnt/linux
# cp /bin/bash /mnt/linux/bin/bash
# cp /bin/dash /mnt/linux/bin/dash
# cp /bin/sh /mnt/linux/bin/sh
```

At this point, I could use `dpkg` again while using `chroot` on my Ubuntu partition. I noticed again, however, that `apt-get` was insisting to remove `dash` again upon each command. So, I reinstalled `dash`:

```
# apt-get install dash
```

Finally, I restarted my computer and booted up into Ubuntu 12.04 just fine. I inspected the package history and these were my results:

[image: http://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/545946_10151063058008668_2004083202_n.jpg]

All events at 5:28 PM were when I blindly executed the recommended TeamViewer 7 installation commands to get into an online meeting:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

At this point, I didn't want any more of TeamViewer. So to clean up further, I purged `teamviewer7:i386` using dpkg:

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge teamviewer7:i386
$ sudo apt-get remove teamviewer7:i386
```

In conclusion, the TeamViewer 7 i386 version for Linux removes `/bin/dash` which is the root of all the symptoms from the terminal failure, to the `dpkg` failure to the boot failure.